# Derivation of Neuhaus, Jewell(1993)

Tags: mathematical-statistics, generalized-linear-model, bias, omitted-variable-bias

I wish to ask a derivation problem in Neuhaus, Jewell(1993) - "A geometric approach to assess bias due to omitted covariates in generalized linear models"

The statistical True model dealt in this paper is

$P[y = 1|X, Z] = g^{-1}(\beta_0 + \beta X + \gamma Z)$

where $X, Z \in R$. Also the assumed Reduced model is

$P[y = 1|X] = g^{-1}(\beta_0^* + \beta^* X)$

According to my understanding, the main purpose of this paper is to find the Marginalized form(wrt $Z$) of the True model, while retaining the assumed Reduced model form. **This is equivalent to finding the relationship between $\beta$ and $\beta^*$.**

In section 2.3, **assuming No Prior Relationship between $X$, $Z$,** the authors claim

$\beta^*(X) \approx (\beta + \delta_Z)H^{'}_X(0)$

$\delta_Z = E[Z|X+1] - E[Z|X]$

$H^{'}_X(0) = g^{'}E[g^{-1}(\gamma Z)|X]E[\frac{1}{g^{'}g^{-1}(\gamma Z)}|X]$

using Taylor Expansion on the naturally derived following relation

$\beta^* = gE[g^{-1}(\beta_0 + \beta (X+1) + \gamma Z)|X+1] -gE[g^{-1}(\beta_0 + \beta X+ \gamma Z)|X] $

The authors do not mention how the Taylor Expansion is implemented, and for me there seems to be a contradicting issue in the claimed form.

- The form claimed by the authors requires Taylor Expansion wrt $\gamma$ around zero in order to have the additive term $\delta_Z$.
- On the other hand, the scaling constant $H^{'}_X(0)$ contains non-trivial $\gamma$, which implies we shouldn't Taylor Expand wrt $\gamma$ around zero.

It would mean much if I could get any comments regarding this issue.